# Preprocessor definitions not propagating from CMake to Unix Makefiles

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, c-preprocessor

I'm having trouble getting anything I pass to CMake using -D or add_definitions() to show up when compiling the Makefiles that CMake creates.

*(Summarized using a trivial example).*

At the top level, I have a build.sh script, that starts with:

```
cmake \
    -G "Unix Makefiles" \
    -DPIZZA=1 \
    -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=1 \
    $TOPPINGS \
    ../../src
```

$TOPPINGS is declared as -DTOPPINGS=ALL previously.  I've verified it's correctly getting passed to the above.  Based on the value of TOPPINGS, my CmakeLists.txt adds some more preprocessor definitions using add_definitions().  For the sake of discussion we'll say it does:

```
add_definitions( -DCHEESE=Mozz ) 
add_definitions( -DMEAT=Meat )
```

This generates without a problem.  In the CMakeCache.txt they appear:

```
//No help, variable specified on the command line.
CHEESE:UNINITIALIZED=Mozz
```

And I've verified my logic using message() in CMakeLists.txt.

But when we build using generated Makefiles, these are not defined.  Neither the ones specified on the invocation to Cmake nor those added through add_definitions.

In looking at the documentation for add_definitions I see:

> Adds definitions to the compiler command line for sources in the
>   current directory and below.

Is this the source of my problem?  I.e.: The definitions are only being added for the directory I'm running CMake from, or is it being added for everything in ../../src (and below) and the problem is elsewhere?  If this is the case, is there a way to manually specify these definitions should apply to ../../src and below?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @steveire mentioned, an SSCCE would be helpful.  Nonetheless, there's a good chance that the problem is related to the order/location of your `add_subdirectory` calls in relation to the `add_definitions` calls.

First, just to be clear, variables set by CMake don't have any bearing on preprocessor definitions unless you explicitly tie them together.  What I mean is that if you call

```
cmake -DTOPPINGS=Haggis .
```

or have `set(TOPPINGS Haggis)` in your CMakeLists.txt, the preprocessor won't see any `Haggis` unless you also have something like

```
add_definitions(-DTOPPINGS=${TOPPINGS})
```

OK, so for an example, consider the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(MyTest)
add_executable(MyTestExe main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(One)
add_definitions(-DTOPPINGS=Haggis)
add_subdirectory(Two)
target_link_libraries(MyTestExe One Two)
```

In this case, targets defined in the CMakeLists.txt of subdir "One" *won't* have `TOPPINGS` as a PP definition since `add_subdirectory(One)` comes before the `add_definitions` call.  If "One" sets any PP definitions using `add_definitions`, they won't propagate back up to the top-level or to "Two".

However, since `add_subdirectory(Two)` comes *after* the `add_definitions` call, all targets defined in there (and any of its subdirs) *will* have `TOPPINGS` as a PP definition.

Finally, the target `MyTestExe` will also have `TOPPINGS` as a PP definition, regardless of where the `add_executable` call comes in relation to the `add_definitions` call.

Some of this confusion can possibly be avoided by using [`target_compile_definitions`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/target_compile_definitions.html) instead of `add_definitions`.  This gives much more fine-grained control of PP definitions; we don't want haggis leaking everywhere!

Say we remove the line `add_definitions(-DTOPPINGS=Haggis)` from the CMakeLists.txt.  Now in the CMakeLists.txt of subdir "Two", we can do:

```
add_library(Two two.hpp two.cpp)
# Note, we don't need to use -D here, but it doesn't matter if you do
target_compile_definitions(Two PUBLIC TOPPINGS=Haggis PRIVATE SIDE=Whisky)
```

This causes the PP definitions `TOPPINGS` *and* `SIDE` to be applied to the single target library `Two`, regardless of how many other targets we may define in the same CMakeList.txt.

Since `TOPPINGS` is declared as `PUBLIC`, it causes CMake to apply it to any other target which links `Two`.  We're doing that in the top-level CMakeLists.txt when we call `target_link_libraries(MyTestExe One Two)`, so `MyTestExe` will also have `TOPPINGS` as a PP definition, but it won't have `SIDE` since that's `PRIVATE` to `Two`.

Comment: Awesome Fraser.  Thanks for the detail in your answer.  It was a combination of -D passed to CMake (insidious how much looks like PP), and ordering.